How to Configure ESLint and Prettier for Correct Error Reporting in TypeScript and Next.js Project
I'm using TypeScript and Next.js. I wanted to enforce code formatting errors, so I added the following rule to eslintrc.json:
"rules": {
  "prettier/prettier": "error"
}

After running npm run build, I encountered the following error in all files:
1:1  Error: Definition for rule 'prettier/prettier' was not found.

These errors do not appear in the code but only in the terminal.
To resolve this, I added the following plugins to eslintrc.json:
"plugins": ["@typescript-eslint", "prettier"]

After running npm run build again, many formatting errors appeared, including some that should not have been displayed (e.g., changing "react" to 'react'). In my project,  'react' is correct.
How can I ensure only the correct errors are displayed? If anyone knows, please help. Thank you.
Prettier Configuration
{
  "tabWidth": 2,
  "trailingComma": "es5",
  "semi": true,
  "singleQuote": true
}

eslintrc.json Configuration
{
  "extends": [
    "plugin:@typescript-eslint/recommended",
    "next/core-web-vitals",
    "prettier"
  ],
  "rules": {
    "prettier/prettier": "error"
  },
  "plugins": ["@typescript-eslint", "prettier"]
}

package.json Configuration
{
  "name": "****",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "dev": "next dev",
    "build": "next build",
    "start": "next start",
    "lint": "next lint",
    "format": "prettier --write --ignore-path .gitignore --ignore-path .prettierignore './**/*.{js,jsx,ts,tsx,json,css}' && next lint --fix"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@chakra-ui/next-js": "^2.1.4",
    "@chakra-ui/react": "^2.7.0",
    "@emotion/react": "^11.11.1",
    "@emotion/styled": "^11.11.0",
    "@hookform/resolvers": "^3.1.1",
    "@types/node": "20.3.1",
    "@types/papaparse": "^5.3.7",
    "@types/plotly.js": "^2.12.25",
    "@types/react": "18.2.12",
    "@types/react-dom": "18.2.5",
    "@types/react-plotly.js": "^2.6.0",
    "axios": "^1.4.0",
    "encoding": "^0.1.13",
    "eslint": "8.42.0",
    "eslint-config-next": "13.4.5",
    "firebase": "^10.0.0",
    "firebase-admin": "^11.11.1",
    "framer-motion": "^10.12.16",
    "next": "^13.4.7",
    "papaparse": "^5.4.1",
    "react": "^18.2.0",
    "react-dom": "18.2.0",
    "react-hook-form": "^7.45.2",
    "react-icons": "^4.9.0",
    "react-markdown": "^9.0.1",
    "remark-gfm": "^4.0.0",
    "swr": "^2.2.0",
    "typescript": "5.1.3",
    "xlsx": "^0.18.5",
    "zod": "^3.21.4"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@typescript-eslint/eslint-plugin": "^6.5.0",
    "@typescript-eslint/parser": "^6.5.0",
    "eslint-config-prettier": "^9.0.0",
    "eslint-plugin-prettier": "^5.0.0",
    "openapi-typescript-codegen": "^0.25.0",
    "prettier": "^3.0.3"
  },
  "volta": {
    "node": "18.17.0"
  }
}

please teach me......
